# Which Cygwin packages does one need to install to run BRAT?

Tags: windows, nlp, cygwin, brat

I run [BRAT](http://brat.nlplab.org) with Cygwin on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. To do so, I run in Cygwin:

```
mkdir brat
cd brat
wget http://weaver.nlplab.org/~brat/releases/brat-v1.3_Crunchy_Frog.tar.gz
tar xzf brat-v1.3_Crunchy_Frog.tar.gz
cd brat-v1.3_Crunchy_Frog
./install.sh -u
python standalone.py
```

At that point, BRAT is now be accessible through the web browser at http://127.0.0.1:8001.

It works fine when I install all the Cygwin packages, but it doesn't if I only perform the minimal Cygwin installation.

Which Cygwin packages does one need to install to run BRAT?

---

I know one has to install python 2:

[image]

However, it doesn't seem to be enough, as when I go to http://127.0.0.1:8001/ I get:

[image]

Comment: Oh, last I used it, I can't really deploy it properly and all the code looks extremely outdated =( I'm afraid it's going to be hard to know which package you'll need to deploy.

Comment: @Franck Dernoncourt - I am in the exact same situation here.  How did you resolve it finally ?

Comment: @Ananth I haven't found a solution. Interestingly, around 1.5 year ago, it was working fine.

Comment: @ Franck Dernoncourt  - I ended up installing Linux subsystem for windows on Windows 10 and followed the steps mentioned here. https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17362/can-brat-be-installed-on-microsoft-windows .   Brat now works fine